# change highcharts tooltip color according to the bar color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do i set the tooltip color to same as the bar color in highcharts version 5?

I used the below code but only the border color of the tooltip seems to be changing

```
  tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: null,
                    formatter: function(){

                        return '<div style="background-color:'+ this.series.color +'!important; font-weight:bold;color:#fff" class="tooltip"> ' + this.y + '</div>';
                    },

                  },
```

Note that the above code works on Highcharts 4 but not in version 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `useHTML: true,` in tooltip options

```
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions',
        useHTML: true,
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: null,
        formatter: function(){
            return '<div style="background-color:'+ this.series.color +'!important; font-weight:bold;color:#fff" class="tooltip"> ' + this.y + '</div>';
        }
    },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/utL6n11y/) demo

**Update**

Using  [Tooltip.prototype.refresh](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) adding this to existing code

```
  const H = Highcharts;

  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (p, point, mouseEvents) {
    p.call(this, point, mouseEvents);

        const label = this.label;

        if (point && label) {
          label.attr({
            fill: point.series.color
          });
        }
      });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utL6n11y/1/)

Comment: Even i use `useHTML: true,` it doesnt work... If you check the fiddle only the text background is changed not the whole tooltip